# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: - AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a `DbAdapter` and a `DbHelper` class into my android app, to handle login and register requests through SQLite, they were working perfectly, until now (maybe a Clean Porject or Rebuild) generated this error, maybe a database reload? I don't know.

This is the actual error if I click on a button in my app (Login):

```
06-26 12:22:08.164  28592-28592/com.example.shairlook E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.kkoci.shairlook.DbHelper
        at com.kkoci.shairlook.DbAdapter.open(DbAdapter.java:38)
        at com.kkoci.shairlook.LoginMember.onCreate(LoginMember.java:57)
```

This is the error code on `DbAdapter` on line 38:

```
 public DbAdapter open() throws SQLException
{
    mDbHelper = new DbHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
```

And the `Login Member Activity`:

```
        dbAdapter = new DbAdapter(this);
        dbAdapter.open();
```

If I click on `Register` button it's the same error, same line on `DbAdapter` and different lines on, `Register Activity` of course:

```
    dbAdapter = new DbAdapter(this);
    dbAdapter.open();
```

If you need further explanation please let me know...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There seems to be two different package names `com.example.shairlook` and `com.kkoci.shairlook` in logs. How so? Did you change the package name of the app but forgot to update the package names of those referenced classes?

Comment: Oh, damn, let me check, yes, maybe the backend I've added recently, let me check out

Comment: Yeah some confusion with package names, Thank you!